# Calculate total price from data of 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have data like:

Table `SALE`:

```
PR_KEY TRAN_ID   TRAN_NO  TRAN_DATE   CUSTOMER_ID USER_ID TABLE_ID PAY_TYPE_ID TOTAL_PRICE  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
187    SALE    130511164  2012-05-27    0000       ADMIN        59        1          0
```

Table `Sale_detail`

```
PR_KEY   FR_KEY    LIST_ORDER    ITEM_ID    PRICE     AMOUNT
--------------------------------------------------------------
281      187        0.0000       9          10000        3
282      187        0.0000       tom        20000        2
```

My question is:

1. Are there any ways for me to push data to `sale.totalprice` by calculating `(SD.Price * SD.Amount)+(SD.Price * SD.Amount)` (for the same `FR_KEY`)
2. Or create a view to show the total price, same calculation `(SD.Price * SD.Amount)+ (SD.Price * SD.Amount)` (for each FR_KEY)

This is for SQL Server, and `FR_KEY` of `sale_detail` references the `Pr_key` of the `Sale` table.

I tried -

```
SELECT dbo.SALE_DETAIL.PR_KEY,
dbo.SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY, 
SUM(dbo.SALE_DETAIL.PRICE * dbo.SALE_DETAIL.AMOUNT) AS Grand_total 
FROM dbo.SALE_DETAIL, dbo.SALE JOIN SALE s 
      on s.PR_KEY = SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY 
WHERE SALE_DETAIL.PR_KEY = @FR_KEY 
ORDER BY PR_KEY
```

The result I want is:

```
PR_KEY TRAN_ID USER_ID TABLE_ID PAY_TYPE_ID TOTAL_PRICE
187    SALE    ADMIN   59       1            70000
```

Comment: You haven't specified what results you want.

Comment: I already do it, sorry for the missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try query below for your second question.

```
SELECT
    SALE.PR_KEY,
    TRAN_ID,
    TRAN_NO,
    TRAN_DATE,
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    USER_ID,
    TABLE_ID,
    PAY_TYPE_ID,
    SUM(PRICE*AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM
    SALE_DETAIL
INNER JOIN SALE 
    ON SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY = SALE.PR_KEY
GROUP BY
    SALE.PR_KEY,
    TRAN_ID,
    TRAN_NO,
    TRAN_DATE,
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    USER_ID,
    TABLE_ID,
    PAY_TYPE_ID
```

Comment: It work for me but when I create my view it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829293/calculate-sum-of-price-from-2-table-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment112871054_63829293. Could you help me find out what was wrong here.

Comment: @PDA I have posted an answer, please check it out now.

Answer (score 2):

The query that you have provided can be simplified to:

```
SELECT sd.PR_KEY, sd.FR_KEY, 
       SUM(sd.PRICE * sd.AMOUNT) AS Grand_total 
FROM dbo.SALE_DETAIL sd 
      on s.PR_KEY = SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY 
WHERE sd.PR_KEY = @FR_KEY 
GROUP BY sd.PR_KEY, sd.FR_KEY;
```

No `JOIN` is necessary.  But `GROUP BY` is.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect oppertunity to use OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT 
   PR_KEY,
   FR_KEY,
   O.Grand_total 
FROM dbo.SALE OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT    SUM(PRICE * AMOUNT) AS Grand_total FROM SALE_DETAIL WHERE FR_KEY =PR_KEY
GROUP BY FR_KEY
) O
WHERE PR_KEY = @FR_KEY 
ORDER BY PR_KEY
```