# Calculate sum of price from 2 table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

After asking about calculate the sum of the total price  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63824072/calculate-total-price-from-data-of-2-tables/63824464#63824464) and Its work but then went I add(SUM(PRICE*AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PRICE) to create my own View, the Total_price = Expr1, It just PRICE * AMOUNT, there is no sum here.

I apply It to create a view
here is the query

```
    SELECT                       SALE_DETAIL.PR_KEY,SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY,dbo.SALE_DETAIL.PRICE * dbo.SALE_DETAIL.AMOUNT AS Expr1, 
      
                         dbo.DM_ITEM.UNIT_ID, dbo.DM_ITEM.ACTIVE AS ACTIVE_ITEM, SUM(PRICE*AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PRICE , dbo.SALE.TOTAL_CHAIR_USE,SALE_DETAIL.ITEM_ID,dbo.SALE_DETAIL.PRICE
FROM                     dbo.DM_ITEM 
                         INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SALE_DETAIL ON dbo.DM_ITEM.ITEM_ID = dbo.SALE_DETAIL.ITEM_ID 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.DM_VAT_TAX ON dbo.SALE_DETAIL.VAT_TAX_ID = dbo.DM_VAT_TAX.VAT_TAX_ID 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SALE 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.DM_TABLES ON dbo.SALE.TABLE_ID = dbo.DM_TABLES.TABLE_ID ON dbo.SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY = dbo.SALE.PR_KEY
WHERE                   (dbo.SALE.IS_PROVISIONAL = 1)
GROUP BY
    SALE.PR_KEY,DM_ITEM.ITEM_NAME,DM_ITEM.ITEM_CLASS_ID,DM_ITEM.UNIT_ID,
    SALE.TABLE_ID,DM_ITEM.ACTIVE,
    SALE.TRAN_ID,SALE_DETAIL.PRICE,
    TRAN_NO,PAY_TYPE_ID,DM_VAT_TAX.VAT_TAX_NAME,
    TRAN_DATE,SALE.COMMENT,
    CUSTOMER_ID,SALE_DETAIL.PR_KEY,SALE_DETAIL.FR_KEY,SALE_DETAIL.LIST_ORDER,SALE_DETAIL.ITEM_ID,SALE_DETAIL.VAT_TAX_ID,
    USER_ID,SALE.TOTAL_CUSTOMER_PAY,SALE.EXPORT_TYPE_ID,SALE.IS_PROVISIONAL,
    DM_TABLES.TABLE_NAME,DM_TABLES.TOTAL_CHAIR,SALE_DETAIL.AMOUNT,SALE.TOTAL_CHAIR_USE,SALE.COST_OTHER,SALE_DETAIL.HOUR_CALL
```

Here  is the output

```
PR_KEY FR_KEY Expr1 UNIT_ID ACTIVE_ITEM TOTAL_PRICE TOTAL_CHAIR_USE ITEM_ID PRICE


 272.00 180.00  710000   7  0           710000      0               LAU_BO  355000.00
273.00  182.00  50000    5  0           50000       0               LON_R   50000.00
274.00  182.00  180000   5  0           180000      0               G_L     180000.00
281.00  187.00  30000    3  0           30000       0               9       10000.00
282.00  187.00  40000    3  0           40000       0               tom     20000.00
283.00  189.00  200000   3  0           200000      0               2       200000.00
295.00  199.00  0.00     0  1           0.00        0               5         0.00
296.00  199.00  0.00     5  0           0.00        0               B_XT    0.00
```

Could anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would help.  You could probably also simplify the query for the purposes of this question.

Comment: the sum of(amount * price) = amount * price. In here the result is like:                                  
272.00 180.00 710000.00 7 0 710000.00 0 LAU_BO 355000.00
273.00 182.00 50000.00 5 0 50000.00 0 LON_R 50000.00
274.00 182.00 180000.00 5 0 180000.00 0 G_L 180000.00
281.00 187.00 30000.00 3 0 30000.00 0 9 10000.00
282.00 187.00 40000.00 3 0 40000.00 0 tom 20000.00
283.00 189.00 200000.00 3 0 200000.00 0 2 200000.00
295.00 199.00 0.00 0 1 0.00 0 5 0.00
296.00 199.00 0.00 5 0 0.00 0 B_XT 0.00

Comment: You've asked 8 questions and NONE of them have been marked as the answer

Comment: Sorry about that, I will mark it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your problem here and the choices you provided on your previous question, pushing sum of prices from `Sale_Detail` to master `Sale` table seems more logical now. You can `UPDATE` (push) your master table by using the previous query with `WITH` function. This way, you can update total price in `Sale` table based on its primary key which is a foreign key in `Sale_Detail` as I understood.

You can adjust your grouping in Sale_Detail table according to your total price summation for the key and other column values.

Please be careful writing and posting queries with such syntax that affects the readability.

```
WITH Sales_CTE (PR_KEY, TOTAL_PRICE)
 AS
 (
SELECT
    Sale.PR_KEY,
    SUM(PRICE*AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM
    Sale_Detail
INNER JOIN Sale 
    ON Sale_Detail.FR_KEY = Sale.PR_KEY
GROUP BY
    Sale.PR_KEY,
    TRAN_ID,
    TRAN_NO,
    TRAN_DATE,
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    USER_ID,
    TABLE_ID,
    PAY_TYPE_ID
)
UPDATE
    Sale
SET
    Sale.TOTAL_PRICE = Sales_CTE.TOTAL_PRICE
FROM
    Sale
INNER JOIN
    Sales_CTE
ON 
    Sales_CTE.PR_KEY = Sale.PR_KEY;
```

Comment: Can I create a View of that Select statement and then call that view in another view ?

Comment: @PDA Views are to simplify your tables, but you should not use views as tables. Views are simply queries. Yes, you can call another view in a view, however it is not recommended due to performance issues. What is the point anyway? Just use the select statement directly. This issue is explained here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance

In my humble opinion, you should search on the internet before throwing questions for you to improve yourself.